# How to Get Int or String Value from Textview setted by placeholder

Tags: android

This is how i am setting text to a `TextView` using a place holder.

```
myTextView.setText(String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.total_savings), totalSavings));
```

This is string resource value

```
<string name="total_savings">Total Savings: %1$d</string>
```

Now, I need to get the value of `%1$d` from the `TextView`.
My question is, how do I get that decimal integer value from the `TextView` by using the `getText()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `totalSavings` stored somewhere in your data structure.

However if you want to get the value from the `TextView` then

```
String input = mTextView.getText().toString();

input = input.subString(15, input.length());
```

Since you are getting the value from a `TextView` where user cannot change data as he pleases, there is no need for validation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Logically it is working as per my requirement but i need to know is there any dedicated method to get value so we can reduce the risk of counting the number of characters to trim.

Comment: @Akshayn.s If you want some built-in *intelligent* method that somehow *magically* gets you exactly what you want, then AFAIK that is not possible. The `TextView` has no idea what kind of data you are showing i.e. whether it can be broken down or not. However you could provide two `TextView`s next to each other: one with label the other with value (savings).

Answer (score 1):

Set this text in String.xml file

```
<string name="total_savings">Total Saving : &#x0025;1$d</string>
```

In Java file for set the text Use

```
myTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.total_savings));
```

To get the value of textview use

```
String output = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I think you dint understand the question